# Matplotlib axis not appearing in saved images

Tags: python, matplotlib, png

**I'll submit this question only because I couldn't find any similar questions.**

Today I was making plots using Python 3.10.4, matplotlib 3.5.2
I used `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(f"[ImageSpecificName{specifier}]".png)` in a loop to save a series of figures that I then sent to a number of people. One of those people was unable to view the titles/axis labels/anything outside the plot area. All other recipients could view them without issue. How is it that one person was unable to see the axis?

Comment: We don't have any information to really help you with this.  Can you reproduce with a minimal set of images (say two) and show us the code you used?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue; whenever I opened the images, I could see the axis. I have tried to get images from the recipient having trouble, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how some image viewing software interpret images. As such, the usual `bboxinches='tight'` option found in some pseudo-similar questions may not help and can produce an error `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: savefig() got unexpected keyword argument "bboxinches" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will become an error in 3.6`

The best solution is to use a file format that isn't png. Testing .svg and .jpg resulted in images with significant artifacts. Using pdf format ensured that the entire image was viewable across the various image viewing software with no noticeable artifacts. As always, review image files before sending them to collaborators/clients, but pdf formatting worked well for me.

Comment: PNG files do not have a concept of a crop box so far as I know, so this is incorrect.  Further, `bbox_inches='tight'` is still very much part of Matplotlib and not deprecated.